# Newbie - datepicker and to string VB

Tags: vb.net, datepicker, tostring

I know this is a really basic question but i'm just starting with VB Studio and this is straight out of the book.

```
    MsgBox("Your birth date was " & DateTimePicker1.Text)
    MsgBox("Day of the year: " & DateTimePicker1.Value.DayOfYear.ToString())
```

I expected the ToString to convert the integer value to a text value of the date but it still returns the nummerical value.  If I watch it is actaully returns the numercial value as a string eg "20".  I have tried to find some info online but i get the same peice of code back that i'm using.

Are there compatabitiy issues with date picker and Win7 (64bit) or am i missing some simple configuration.

I'd appreciate any support on this simple problem.

Thank you
Damian

Comment: What value do you expect for DayOfYear()? DayOfYear is the numerical day of the year, so Feburary 1st returns 32 (It is the 32nd day of the year).  Update the question with an example date that is displayed in the date picker and what you expect the output to be.

Answer (score 0):

The ToString function does not convert integers to literal strings. It is use to convert objects or fields to Strings which are suitable for display. Therefore it convert the integer 2 to the string "2".

Try using custom format to get your date in the proper format

[Look at this link to get started](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.customformat.aspx)

Comment: Thanks GrayB I'll look at this.  The code snippet is straight out of the MS VB 2010 step by step book and suggests it should work.

Comment: According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx the ToString method should work in this way when used with the date time object.  clearly i'm confused.  It doesn't help when the first example in the book doesn't function as described :-(

Comment: @user1406454 I went into the book and tried the example and I believe that it is suppose to return the day of the year as it is written: "A second message box appears, indicating the **day of the year** on which you were born"